# How to write a script with Android Debug Bridge command in it

Tags: shell-script, scripting, android, adb

I am trying to write a script to automate some testing, and the fist step is connect to my device and update the /lib/modules/ directory with the recent version of a device driver on my host. That is I need to push the updated file from my host machine to the phone. Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
adb shell mount | grep -e "modules"
echo
adb shell "su -c 'mount -o remount, rw /lib/modules/'"
echo
adb shell mount | grep -e "modules"
echo
```

But the above does not work, and I do not know how to get more information about it. Here is the output I get: `mount: Invalid argument`
I am also not able to update the phone with the most recent file.

Comment: The answer for me was to write to /sdcard and the copy the file to whatever destination you want. Since my phone is rooted, I can use a superuser command to move files from and to anywhere I want.

Comment: Try `mount -o remount,rw /lib/modules` without the space after the comma.

Comment: I tried the above command, but I get the following error: root@hltespr:/ # mount -o remount,rw /lib/modules
Usage: mount [-r] [-w] [-o options] [-t type] device directory